# Service Worker not registered in Heroku - Angular PWA

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I am trying to deploy an Angular PWA on Heroku, but I can't seem to figure it out.
The deployed app works great, however no service worker is registered according to LightHouse, therefore it is not a PWA.

Here is the process I am using to deploy :

1. Run `ng build --prod` in the angular project
2. Copy the dist/myapp folder next to my server.js file
3. Commit and push to heroku.

Before pushing, running `npm run start` or `http-server dist/myapp` works just fine locally, a service worker is registered and the app is installable.

Here is my start command in *package.json* and my post-deploy command in *ecosystem.config.js*:

```
"start": "pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
```

Note: It uses node.js and express to load an Angular project using this method : `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/myapp')));`

Does anyone have an idea as to why it does not register a service worker on Heroku ?